# NSURLConnection issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I am using the NSURLConnection class to establish a connection with the server. In my project I am using two different servers for multiple web-services. I have found one issue with my application. When my application is in the foreground and remains idle for about 15-20 mins all the web-services from the 1st server stops with a "Request Time Out" Error.

Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x1c89b880 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://xxx.xxxxx.co.in/xxxx.svc, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://xxx.xxxxx.co.in/xxxx.svc, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSUnderlyingError=0x17666310 "The request timed out."}

Reuqest format -

```
NSString* rr = @"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"xxxxx" xmlns:tem=\"xxxxxx" xmlns:ns=\"xxxxxxx"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><tem:xxxx><tem:zzz>cc</tem:zzz></tem:xxxx></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";   
NSMutableURLRequest *r = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"xxxx"]];
[r addValue: @"text/xml; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[r addValue: @"xxxx"  forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[r addValue: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[rr length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[r setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[r setHTTPBody: [rr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

While the other web-services from another server works proper within same timeframe. Also when i quit application and relaunch all web-services starts working proper.

Please suggest solution.

Comment: some problem with the server ?

Comment: Server works fine as if i exit app and start again the same server respond very quickly. so i can't claim on server issue.

Comment: could you post some code ?

Comment: @Yash Sodha - Please recheck edited question.

Comment: @Yash Sodha - Please answer my question.

Comment: Hey !! No idea then bro